# Прилипание блока к другому при прокрутке

Tags: html, css

Есть блок, который содержит в себе другие блоки, нужно чтобы при прокрутке он прилипал к шапке сайта и не уходил под неё.

```
<div class="popular_articles">
        <p class="title">Популярные:</p>
        <div class="top_articles">
            <a href="">Название статьи</a>
            <p class="number_articles">Cтатья №1</p>
            <img src="img/logo.png">
            <p>Аккуратно бреющийся мужчина старуха изергиль была истинно русской натурой, очень любила природу. Здесь была маруся кота и сам. Тучи выглянул луч солнца и тут боец вспомнил, что нередко наблюдается. Мелкий и четырёх пар ног распахнута. Глаза с дочерью мензурку спал. Только французские слова, кроме слова дура борис не только. Слышала от него винтовка бы так сделать! длинными зимними холодными.</p>   
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.popular_articles 
{
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top:150px;
    width: 300px;
    height:700px;
    z-index:-2;
}
.popular_articles .title
{
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    left: 55px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: -2;
}
.top_articles
{
    background-color: black;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;

}
.top_articles img
{
    background-color: maroon;
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-top:-40px;

}
.top_articles a
{
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
    left:55px;

}
```

Шапка:

```
<div class="top">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.top
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 110px; 
    background-color: black;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Если можно реализовать на css, если нет то на простом js(его не изучал, имею только базовые представления).
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Такое через js-реализуется: отслеживается top-позиция блока. Если знаний не хватает, то используйте jQuery-плагин. Например ScrollToFixed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $.fn.followTo = function (pos) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function (e) {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 10
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 150
            });
        }
    });
};

$('.float-block').followTo(140);
});
```

```css
section{
  max-width: 600px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.col-md-10{
  min-height: 900px;
} 
.content-block{
  padding: 15px;
}
.float-block{
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 150px;
}
.col-md-10{
  width: 80%;
  float:left;
}
.col-md-2{
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Fixed block on scroll</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="content-block">
            <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
            <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

<p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

<p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
    <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

<p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

<p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="float-block">
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Правильно я понял вопрос? Чтобы блок при скролле фиксировался?
[Тут](https://smartideal.net/fiksirovannyj-blok-vo-vremya-skrolla/) есть более подробное описание.

Comment: Cпасибо. Буду изучать

Answer (score 0):

На CSS

```css
.raz {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 1em; /* ширина шапки */
  min-height: 2em;
  background: lightpink;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="raz">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
   <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
     <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
  <div class="sticky"> Я прилипучка!!!!!!!!!!!!!! </div>
   <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
     <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
       <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
         <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
           <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
             <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
              <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div> <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div> <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div> <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
               <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum, magni alias cum ab ad explicabo consequatur ea omnis eligendi fugiat, quia. Voluptatem deserunt ad accusantium cupiditate in molestiae, quo soluta.</div>
                
</div>
```

Comment: На IE работать не будет к сожалению

Comment: К сожалению да. Если нужна его поддержка то тогда только js.